# how to use mutiple login with java and database

Tags: python, c#, html, database, javac

I am fail on one section of an project given to me in which I have to create a one login for two different types of user which will display two different menus depending on which login is used. I am using NetBeans IDE and database

The two different types of user are manager and Worker and they must login using a username and password. The manager menu must have the following menu options after logging in:

1 Setup Worker files
2 View Worker files
3 Move Worker files
4 Add workers files
5 update workers files
The Worker menu must have the following menu options after logging in:

1 View workers files

And when the manager move or add or update the file automatically changed to the workers menu

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java and want to work with databases, look at the Spring Framework suite (more specifically Spring Boot).

As for working with the login functionality, implementation will vary but **never ever ever store plain text passwords in a database**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).